# Switching the rows and columns of a PHP array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, export-to-csv

I have an array filled with arrays. Each array within the master array contains data scraped from a realty website. When I output them to a CSV file I want to make each category of data (price, address, size, etc...) its own separate column. Right now, each category is stored within a row. I have looked a few threads here about this and cannot get the code to work. I think it's because this array does not contain strings, it contains arrays that each contain strings. I would like to know how to accomplish this. I tried doing array_flip() however it returned an error that said the array must contain strings or numbers.

Here is what I have right now:

```
<?php

            //URL HERE 

            $html = file_get_contents("URL_HERE");   
            $DOM = new DOMDocument();
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $DOM->loadHTML($html);


            // price

            $pfinder = new DomXPath($DOM);
            $classname_p = 'price-large';
            $pnodes = $pfinder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname_p')]");
            $csv_values_p = array();
            foreach ($pnodes as $pnode) {
                $csv_values_p[] = $pnode->nodeValue;
            }              

            // zestimate

            $zfinder = new DomXPath($DOM);
            $classname_z = 'zestimate';
            $znodes = $zfinder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname_z')]");
            $csv_values_z = array();
            foreach ($znodes as $znode) {
                $csv_values_z[] = $znode->nodeValue;
            }

            // address

            $afinder = new DomXPath($DOM);
            $classname_a = 'property-address';
            $anodes = $afinder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname_a')]");                
            $csv_values_a = array();
            foreach ($anodes as $anode) {
                $csv_values_a[] = $anode->nodeValue;     
            }                

            // property details

            $dfinder = new DomXPath($DOM);
            $classname_d = 'property-data';
            $dnodes = $dfinder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname_d')]");
            $csv_values_d = array();
            foreach ($dnodes as $dnode) {
                $csv_values_d[] = $dnode->nodeValue;     
            } 

            // lot size

            $lfinder = new DomXPath($DOM);
            $classname_l = 'property-lot';
            $lnodes = $lfinder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname_l')]");
            $csv_values_l = array();
            foreach ($lnodes as $lnode) {
                $csv_values_l[] = $lnode->nodeValue;     
            } 

            // year built

            $yfinder = new DomXPath($DOM);
            $classname_y = 'property-year';
            $ynodes = $yfinder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname_y')]");
            $csv_values_y = array();
            foreach ($ynodes as $ynode) {
                $csv_values_y[] = $ynode->nodeValue;     
            }                               

            // Master Array:

            $outputarray = array($csv_values_p,$csv_values_z,$csv_values_a,$csv_values_d,$csv_values_l,$csv_values_y);

            var_dump($outputarray);

            // Export to .CSV:

            $fp = fopen('propertydata3.csv', "w") or die($php_errormsg);
            foreach ($outputarray as $output) {
                fputcsv($fp, $output);
            }
            fclose($fp);

            ?>
```

Comment: if there's no single function that can do this, then write some `foreach` loops

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. I am unable to test it because I do not have any data to test it with.

You may run into issues with this method if there are empty fields in the data you are getting.

If this does not solve your problem, a image of the output data would be great. If I could have some data to work with, that would be even better.

**PHP:**

```
    <?php

    //URL HERE 
    $html = file_get_contents("URL_HERE");   
    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $DOM->loadHTML($html);


    // price
    $pfinder = new DomXPath($DOM);
    $classname_p = 'price-large';
    $pnodes = $pfinder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname_p')]");

    // zestimate
    $zfinder = new DomXPath($DOM);
    $classname_z = 'zestimate';
    $znodes = $zfinder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname_z')]");

    // address
    $afinder = new DomXPath($DOM);
    $classname_a = 'property-address';
    $anodes = $afinder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname_a')]");                          

    // property details
    $dfinder = new DomXPath($DOM);
    $classname_d = 'property-data';
    $dnodes = $dfinder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname_d')]");


    // lot size
    $lfinder = new DomXPath($DOM);
    $classname_l = 'property-lot';
    $lnodes = $lfinder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname_l')]");


    // year built
    $yfinder = new DomXPath($DOM);
    $classname_y = 'property-year';
    $ynodes = $yfinder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname_y')]");                           


    //Count one node
    $count = count($pnodes);
    $outputarray = array();
    for($x = 0; $x > $count; $x++){
        $tempArray = array();
        $tempArray[] = $pnodes[$x];
        $tempArray[] = $znodes[$x];
        $tempArray[] = $anodes[$x];
        $tempArray[] = $dnodes[$x];
        $tempArray[] = $lnodes[$x];
        $tempArray[] = $ynodes[$x];
        $outputarray[] = $tempArray;
    }

    // Master Array:
    //$outputarray = array($csv_values_p,$csv_values_z,$csv_values_a,$csv_values_d,$csv_values_l,$csv_values_y);

    var_dump($outputarray);

    // Export to .CSV:

    $fp = fopen('propertydata3.csv', "w") or die($php_errormsg);
    foreach ($outputarray as $output) {
        fputcsv($fp, $output);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    ?>
```